# Код исправления ошибок в памяти (ECC)

Tags: память, железо, байты, микроархитектура

Не могу понять следующий отрывок из книги Эндрю Таненбаума "Архитектура компьютера" из раздела про коды исправления ошибок, интервал Хэмминга и тд.:

> Возможности проверки и исправления ошибок определенного кода зависят от его интервала Хэмминга. Для обнаружения `d` одноразрядных ошибок необходим код с интервалом `d + 1`, поскольку `d` ошибок не могут превратить одно допустимое кодовое слово в другое допустимое кодовое слово. Соответственно, для исправления `d` одноразрядных ошибок необходим код с интервалом `2d + 1`, поскольку в этом случае допустимые кодовые слова настолько сильно отличаются друг от друга, что даже если произойдет `d` изменений, изначальное кодовое слово окажется ближе к ошибочному, чем любое другое кодовое слово, поэтому его без труда можно будет выявить.

Не понимаю логики, разве интервал Хэмминга не будет равен как раз таки числу ошибок? Ведь как Таненбаум упоминал ранее

> Число битовых позиций, по которым отличаются два слова, называется
> **интервалом Хэмминга**

Следовательно, если произойдет 3 ошибки значит между правильным и ошибочным словом будет 3 отклонения и значит интервал Хэмминга между этими словами будет равный 3.